# getting: Error TypeError: _this.props.saveFileInputAnswer is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I make the call below, I want to pass a url to `this.props.saveFileInputAnswer` but I get a an error saying `Error TypeError: _this.props.saveFileInputAnswer` is not a function. `saveFileInputAnswer` is defined in a parent component and called as a props in the present component.

```
Axios({
  url: CLOUDINARY_URL,
  method: "POST",
  skipAuthorization: true,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  data: fd
})
  .then(response => {
    this.getFileUrl(response.data.secure_url);

    if (response.statusText === "OK") {
      this.setState({ isLoading: false });
      //console.log(this.state);
      toast("File Upload Successful");
      this.props.saveFileInputAnswer(
        this.state.fileUrl,
        this.props.item._id
      );
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("Error", error);
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are not passing saveFileInputAnswer to Child component as props. You need to pass down saveFileInputAnswer to the Child component. Since you haven’t shared how your parent component looks like, consider below example for better understanding

Consider you have saveFileInputAnswer declared in component A.

```
     class AComponent extends Component{

            saveFileInputAnswer = () => {

            }

            render(){
                 return(
                     <div><BComponent saveFileInputAnswer={this.saveFileInputAnswer} /></div>
                 )
             }
     }
```

Now in component B you can access this.props.saveFileInputAnswer

Comment: Thank you so much. I actually saw my mistake. Your solution worked.

Comment: @Uche You are welcome. Please do upvote and accept the answer if resolves your issue so that it will help future readers reading this post